# 複数のGoogleカレンダーの週間予定を習得しLINEに通知をしたいです。

Tags: google-apps-script, line, google-calendar-api

### やりたい事

複数のGoogleカレンダーの週間予定を習得しLINEに通知をしたいです。

- 予定がない時は通知をしない
- 日付をまたぐ予定は開始日の日付しか表示をしない。

初心者な者でうまくできません。アドバイスよろしくお願い致します。

### ソースコード

```js
    const lineToken = "LINE　コード";

function q219287() {
    const today = new Date();
    const days = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(function (d) { return (new Date()).setDate(today.getDate() + d);});
    const events = days.reduce(function (a, c) {
        const eves = getEvents(c);
        return eves.length === 0 ? a : a.concat([c, eves]);
    },[]);
    if(events.length === 0) { return; }
    const message = events.map(function (e) { return [toDate(e[0])].concat(e[1].map(eventAsText));}).join("\n");
    sendToLine(message);
}

function getEvents(thedate) {
    const calendars = {
        "①@group.calendar.google.com" : "①",
        "②@group.calendar.google.com" : "②",
        "③@group.calendar.google.com" : "③",
        "④@group.calendar.google.com" : "④",
        "⑤@group.calendar.google.com" : "⑤",
        "⑥@gmail.com" : "⑥",
    };
    return Object.keys(calendars).map(function (e) { return CalendarApp.getCalendarById(e);}).map(function (cal) {
        return [calendars[e], getEventsStartsInTheDay(cal, thedate)];
    }).filter(function (e) {
        return e[1].length > 0;
    });
}

function eventAsText(events) {
    return events.map(function (e) {
        return '◆ ' + e[0] + '\n' + e[1].map(eventToString).join('\n\n');
    }).join('\n');
}
function sendToLine(text) {
    const token = lineToken;
    const options = {
        "method": "post",
        "payload": "message=" + text,
        "headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", options);
}

function toTime(targetdate, basedate) {
    const min = Utilities.formatDate(str, 'JST', "mm");
    const hour = Utilities.formatDate(str, 'JST', "HH");
    if(targetdate.getDate() === basedate.getDate()) {
        return hour + ":" + min;
    }
    const target = new Date(targetdate.getFullYear(), targetdate.getMonth(), targetdate.getDate());
    const base = new Date(basedate.getFullYear(), basedate.getMonth(), basedate.getDate());
    const datediff = Math.floor(target - base / 86400000);
    return ("0" + ((hour - 0) + 24 * datediff)).slice(-2) + ":" + min;
}
function toDate(date) {
    return Utilities.formatDate(dt, 'JST', '★ MM/dd(' + ["日", "月", "火", "水", "木", "金", "土"][date.getDay()] + ')');
}

function getEventsStartsInTheDay(calendar, thedate) {
    const dateNum = thedate.getDate();// 219287 のエラーからすると (new Date(thedate)).getDate(); か。
    return calendar.getEventsForDay(thedate).filter(function (e) {
        return e.getStartTime().getDate() === dateNum;
    });
}
function eventToString(event) {
    const start = event.getStartTime();
    return toTime(start, start) + ' - ' + toTime(event.getEndTime(), start) + '\n ' + event.getTitle() + '\n\n';
}
// 219287
// 219724 style
function sendTodaySchedule() {
    var accessToken = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('LINE_TOKEN');

    const message = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6].map(function (d) { return getMessage(d);}).filter(function (e) { return e !== "";}).join("\n");
    if (!_isNull(message)) {
        const options =
            {
                'method': 'post'
                , 'payload': 'message=' + message
                , 'headers': {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken}
                , muteHttpExceptions: true
            };
        UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify', options);
    }
}

function getMessage(prm) {
    const week = ['日', '月', '火', '水', '木', '金', '土'];

    var arrCals = [];
    arrCals.push(CalendarApp.getCalendarById('Googleカレンダー@gmail.com'));
    arrCals.push(CalendarApp.getCalendarById('Googleカレンダー@group.calendar.google.com'));//①
    arrCals.push(CalendarApp.getCalendarById('Googleカレンダー@group.calendar.google.com'));//②
    arrCals.push(CalendarApp.getCalendarById('Googleカレンダー@group.calendar.google.com'));//③
    arrCals.push(CalendarApp.getCalendarById('Googleカレンダー@group.calendar.google.com'));//④
    arrCals.push(CalendarApp.getCalendarById('Googleカレンダー@group.calendar.google.com'));//⑤

    var date = new Date();
    var strHeader = '';
    date = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + prm);
    strHeader += Utilities.formatDate(date, 'JST', 'yyyy/M/d')
        + '(' + week[date.getDay()] + ') の予定\n';

    var strBody = getEvents(arrCals, date);
    //if ( _isNull(strBody) ) strBody = '予定はありません。';
    return _isNull(strBody) ? '' : strHeader + strBody;
}

function getEvents(prmarrCals, prmDate) {
    var strEvents = '';
    var strStart = '';
    var strEnd = '';
    var strTime = '';
    var strLocation = '';
    var strDescription = '';
    if (!_isNull(prmarrCals)) {
        for (var j = 0; j < prmarrCals.length; j++) {
            var currentEvents = '';
            var arrEvents = prmarrCals[j].getEventsForDay(new Date(prmDate));
            for (var i = 0; i < arrEvents.length; i++) {
//                if (!_isNull(strEvents)) strEvents += '\n';
                var starts = arrEvents[i].getStartTime();
                if (starts.getDate() !== prmDate.getDate()) continue;
                strStart = _HHmm(starts);
                strEnd = toTime(arrEvents[i].getEndTime(), starts);
                if (strStart === strEnd) {
                    strTime = '終日';
                } else {
                    strTime = strStart + '～' + strEnd;
                }
                currentEvents += '･' + strTime + '【' + arrEvents[i].getTitle() + '】';
                strLocation = arrEvents[i].getLocation();
                strDescription = arrEvents[i].getDescription();
                if (!_isNull(strLocation)) currentEvents += '\n　場所：' + strLocation;
                if (!_isNull(strDescription)) currentEvents += '\n　説明：' + strDescription;
            }
            if (_isNull(currentEvents)) continue;
            if (!_isNull(strEvents)) strEvents += '\n';
            strEvents += prmarrCals[j].getName() + '\n' + currentEvents;
        }
    }
    return strEvents;
}

function _HHmm(str) {
    return Utilities.formatDate(str, 'JST', 'HH:mm');
}

function _isNull(prm) {
    if (prm == '' || prm === null || prm === undefined) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
//219724
//236158 style
const token = "LINE_TOKEN";

const calendarTitleMap = {
    "①@group.calendar.google.com" : "①",
    "②@group.calendar.google.com" : "②",
    "③@group.calendar.google.com" : "③",
    "④@group.calendar.google.com" : "④",
    "⑤@group.calendar.google.com" : "⑤",
    "⑥@gmail.com" : "⑥",

};

const weekday = ["日", "月", "火", "水", "木", "金", "土"];

function notifyWeekly() {
    var _counter = 0;
    const calendars = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
    var dt = new Date()
    var message = "週間予定\n\n";

    for ( var i = 3;  i < 8;  i++ ) {

        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 2);
        message += Utilities.formatDate(dt, 'JST', '★ MM/dd(' + weekday[dt.getDay()] + ')') + "\n";

        var dayText = "";
        for(j in calendars) {
            var calendar = calendars[j];

            var calendarName = calendarTitleMap[calendar.getId()]
            if ( calendarName == undefined ) {
                continue;
            }

            var events = calendar.getEventsForDay(dt);
            if( events.length == 0 ) {
                continue;
            }

            dayText += "< " + calendarName + " >\n";
            for(j in events) {
                var tmp = toDayText(events[j], dt);
                dayText += tmp === "" ? "" : tmp + "\n";
            }
            //dayText += "\n"
        }

        if ( dayText == "") {
            dayText += "予定はありません\n\n";
            counter++;
        }
        message += dayText;
    }
    if(_counter === 5) { return; }
    sendToLine(message);
}

function toDayText(event, date) {
    const st = event.getStartTime();
    if(st.getDate() !== date.getDate()) { return ""; }
    return toTimeText(st) + ' - ' + toTime(event.getEndTime(), st) + " " + event.getTitle() + '\n';
}

function toTimeText(str){
    return Utilities.formatDate(str, 'JST', 'HH:mm');
}
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/231795

Comment: 「やりたい事」に対して、今現在のコードで「どんな問題があるのか」の説明が必要だと思います。